# FileNotFoundException when running class in a jar from servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, filenotfoundexception

In eclipse IDE,there is a standalone java application which reads files.The files are all in a folder under the project.
I created another web application and wrote a servlet and added the jar file of the above application in WEB_INF/lib so that I can use all the classes in it.The servlet is pretty simple but the java application is unable to read files as it used to earlier.I get java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the path specified).
I checked the jar file and it contains the folder containing the files to be read.I even tried adding the folder to the classpath in TOMCAT . but still I cannot get rid of that error.Can someone tell me what is wrong?

The place where I get the error

```
public class KnowledgeSummaryServlet extends HttpServlet {

Answerer a = new Answerer();
```

The class Answerer is something like this

```
public class Answerer {
Lookup lvg  = new Lookup("resources/test/xyz", "resources/test/test.txt");
```

This is the error trace once I run the servlet

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\test\xyz (The system cannot              
find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at com.Lookup.localInitialize(Lookup.java:49)
at com.Lookup.<init>(Lookup.java:44)
at com.Answerer.<init>(Answerer.java:27)
at com.web.KnowledgeSummaryServlet.<init>(KnowledgeSummaryServlet.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It's quite strange that you get a `FileNotFoundException` while reading resources from the classpath. This suggests that you're attempting to access classpath resources by the local disk file system means instead of by classpath means, which would make no sense. Can you please edit your question to show the code of your attempt and paste the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not get classpath resources as local disk file system resources using `FileInputStream`. This makes no sense. Get classpath resources as classpath resources using `ClassLoader`.

Given that you're in a servlet and assuming that the `/resources` folder is part of the classpath, just get them as follows:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream xyzInput = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test/xyz");
InputStream txtInput = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test/test.txt");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks,That worked.But in future while deploying,is there a way to get things to work without adding the folder to the classpath?Cant the folder be fetched from the jar file of the java application??

Comment: The classpath also covers all JARs.